# Batch file to move all subfolder files up then delete empty subfolders?

Tags: batch-file, command-line

I have a folder that contains many subfolders, each with different files in them:

```
C:/folder/subfolder1/file1.jpg,
C:/folder/subfolder2/file2.jpg,
C:/folder/subfolder3/file3.jpg, 
etc.
```

How can I create a batch file that moves the files in the subfolders to the folder, then deletes the empty subfolders.

ie. After the bat file is run, the folder structure should be as follows:

```
C:/folder/file1.jpg
C:/folder/file2.jpg
C:/folder/file3.jpg 
etc.
```

Comment: Your question should include some evidence that you have attempted to answer it. Please include anything you have already tried.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

try this

```
@echo off
for /f "tokens=*" %%f in ('dir /a:-D /s /b') do move "%%f" .
for /f "tokens=*" %%f in ('dir /a:D /s /b') do rd "%%f"
```

Comment: how to I automatically rename the moved file if there is a name conflict? ie file 1, file 1 (1)

Comment: rename the files, not overwrite. :)

Comment: This works, but it's rather dangerous, it traverses all the way down the folder tree. If you have subfolders with more subfolders (like music albums) it will dump ALL the files into the parent directory. Just a warning!

Comment: Hi guys ... I used these command with the /Y parameter but it would seem that the file was still overwritten

Comment: First it didn't work so i added pause after in the end to see whats happening. Found out that my files aint being moved n says Access is denied. Tried running as administrator but the bat doesn't even work then.

Answer (score 1):

This will go through every folder in `%root%` (C:\folder) and copy the contents to `%root%` -

```
@echo off
set root=c:\folder
for /f %%a in ('dir /b /ad %root%') do (
    for /f %%b in ('dir /b %root%\%%a') do move "%root%\%%a\%%b" "%root%\%%b"
    rmdir "%root%\%%a"
)
```

Comment: unless you add "tokens=*" option you will miss the files with space in the filename

Answer (score 0):

I used this as a batch file to move all files from subfolders in the current folder then delete the empty folders.

```
rem Copy all files from subfolders in the current folder to the current folder.
for /R %cd% %%G IN (*.*) DO move /Y "%%G"
rem Move all directories into a temp folder in the current folder.
for /D %%I in (*) do move /y %%I %cd%\temp
rem Remove the temp folder including empty folders.
rmdir /s/q %cd%\temp
```